# count of frequency of variable in second row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like below and I am looking for simple solution for count of variable for column names start with number. after adding second row in dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(AA=c(72,62,43,66,54,64,47,47,27,68),
                 BB=c("AMK","KAMl","HAJ","NHS","KUL","GAF","BGA","NHU","VGY","NHU"),
                 CC=c("TAMAN","GHUSI","KELVIN","DEREK","LOKU","MNDHUL","JASMIN","BINNY","BURTAM","DAVID"),
                 DD=c(62,41,37,41,32,74,52,75,59,36),
                 EE=c("CA","NY","GA","DE","MN","LA","GA","VA","TM","BA"),
                 FF=c("ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","RUSSIAN"),
                 GG=c(33,44,51,51,37,58,24,67,41,75),
                 `1A`=c("","D","","NA","","D","","","D",""),
                 `2B`=c("","A","","","A","A","A","A","",""),
                 `3C`=c("","","","","","","","","",""),
                 `4D`=c("","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","",""),
                  "Concatenate" = c("","DAG","G","NAG","AG","DAG","AG","AG","D",""))
```

he output should be look like below. it will be like count of values for columns names which start with any number and sum of total in last column. after adding a second row in data frame.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your row with

```
summary_row = 
  df %>% 
  summarize(across(c(matches("^[0-9]"), Concatenate), ~sum(!is.na(.) & . != "" & . != "NA")))

summary_row
#   1A 2B 3C 4D Concatenate
# 1  3  5  0  7           8

result = bind_rows(mutate(summary_row, across(everything(), as.character)), df)
# reorder columns
result[names(df)]
#    AA   BB     CC DD   EE      FF GG 1A 2B 3C 4D Concatenate
# 1  NA <NA>   <NA> NA <NA>    <NA> NA  3  5  0  7           8
# 2  72  AMK  TAMAN 62   CA ENGLISH 33                        
# 3  62 KAMl  GHUSI 41   NY  FRENCH 44  D  A     G         DAG
# 4  43  HAJ KELVIN 37   GA ENGLISH 51           G           G
# 5  66  NHS  DEREK 41   DE  FRENCH 51 NA        G         NAG
# 6  54  KUL   LOKU 32   MN ENGLISH 37     A     G          AG
# 7  64  GAF MNDHUL 74   LA ENGLISH 58  D  A     G         DAG
# 8  47  BGA JASMIN 52   GA SPANISH 24     A     G          AG
# 9  47  NHU  BINNY 75   VA ENGLISH 67     A     G          AG
# 10 27  VGY BURTAM 59   TM SPANISH 41  D                    D
# 11 68  NHU  DAVID 36   BA RUSSIAN 75
```

You could bind it to the top of your data frame with the `bind_rows`, but only do so for presentation purposes. Data frame columns can only have one type, so the numbers in the summary row will be converted to characters if they are combined with the `character` columns you already have.

---

I used this data (adding `check.names = FALSE` to your `data.frame()` code so that the column names show up as in your example):

```
df <- data.frame(AA=c(72,62,43,66,54,64,47,47,27,68),
                 BB=c("AMK","KAMl","HAJ","NHS","KUL","GAF","BGA","NHU","VGY","NHU"),
                 CC=c("TAMAN","GHUSI","KELVIN","DEREK","LOKU","MNDHUL","JASMIN","BINNY","BURTAM","DAVID"),
                 DD=c(62,41,37,41,32,74,52,75,59,36),
                 EE=c("CA","NY","GA","DE","MN","LA","GA","VA","TM","BA"),
                 FF=c("ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","RUSSIAN"),
                 GG=c(33,44,51,51,37,58,24,67,41,75),
                 `1A`=c("","D","","NA","","D","","","D",""),
                 `2B`=c("","A","","","A","A","A","A","",""),
                 `3C`=c("","","","","","","","","",""),
                 `4D`=c("","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","",""),
                  "Concatenate" = c("","DAG","G","NAG","AG","DAG","AG","AG","D",""), check.names = F)
```

Comment: but this is not coving column sum of  required variables

Comment: and also the concat column should be in last

Comment: In output I am getting this..

Concatenate AA BB CC DD EE FF GG X1A X2B X3C X4D
8 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: the output should be like :

AA BB CC DD EE FF GG X1A X2B X3C X4D Concatenate
       3 5  7 8

Comment: Okay, I took your picture literally and the *"columns names which start with any number"* literally It looks like your names are actually `X1A, X2B, ...`. If you want to match column names that start with X and a number change `matches("^[0-9]")` to `matches("^X[0-9]")`

Comment: No actually in my original data  column names are like "1.City" , "12.  Dept of Sector"

also the Concatenate column should always be last column
also total of concatenate with sum of total of (3,5,7) in this case

Comment: I've edited my answer to reorder the columns in the original order and show intermediate results. I get the results you want from the data you shared.

Comment: Hi just one more thing when i am applying it to my actual data , it working fine but it changing my  like , my column which start with  number are at last , but by applying this all the columns are coming at first, and i dont want to change my original data. do we have solution for this...???

Comment: If you're using a different data name (e.g., `result` for the result, `df` for the original) then `result[names(df)]` will restore the original order. If you're using the same name, then record the original order before doing anything (`orig_order = names(df)`) and restore it at the end (`df <- df[orig_order]`).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` with `colSums`

```
nm1 <- grep('^[0-9]', names(df), value = TRUE)
colSums(!is.na(df[nm1]) & df[nm1] != "" & df[nm1] != "NA")
```